# Retrieving cell value from a gridview and in database ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that looks like this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actual">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Actual") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Actual") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Target_Amt">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Target_Amt") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Target_Amt") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Month" HeaderText="Month" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MetGoal">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="result" runat="server"><%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Actual")) < Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Target_Amt")) ? "Yes" : "No" %></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I want to be able to store the value (e.g. NO) from this label into my database. How can I achieve that?

```
                <asp:Label ID="result" runat="server"><%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Actual")) < Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Target_Amt")) ? "Yes" : "No" %></asp:Label>
```

Here's a photo of the webpage
[Here's a photo of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tazi5.png)

Comment: In which part of code you need to value from the label? In click of some button?

Comment: I do not have any sort of button in my code. Was wondering if I could just get the value of the cell and sort it in @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Because I am checking if the value in "Actual" is greater than "Target_Amt", it will update as 'N' in the gridview... Or is there other way I can do it?

Comment: Yes and no values are generated at run time while grid is rendering so you can not sort on that column. You can have MetGoal in the original data source itself and then use BoundField to show MetGoal value. And then you can do sorting on MetGoal directly.

Comment: You use Case statement in query Instead of check Label's in Grid view ,           Query - select  case when CAST(Actual AS int)<CAST(Target_Amt AS int) then 'Yes' else 'No' end MetGoal from YourTableName

Comment: you can use Case statement in Query instead of checking label's in grid view, Example - select case when CAST(Actual AS DECIMAL(7,2)) < CAST(Target_Amt AS DECIMAL(7,2)) then 'Yes' else 'No' end MetGoal from TableName